# Format Telephone Number in GridView

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview, formatting, string-formatting

I see another thread somewhat like my question at:

[ASP.NET GridView Column - formatting telephone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180403/asp-net-gridview-column-formatting-telephone-number)

but i do not know if it answers my question as he is using code-behind to make the colum. All I did was insert the GridView control in visual studio. BTW, the data is being populated in the Grid, I am just trying to get the formatting set now.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2010. (Also SQL Management Studio for my database but this information may not be needed, just trying to give enough to make sure what i am doing is understood)

I am making a website in ASP.NET with Visual Basic.net code behind.

The site is basically a contact list site.

3 Text Box Fields. First Name, Last Name, Main Phone #.

Add Record Button (Takes the information from the text boxes and inserts into a database)

GridView that shows the database that is being populated with the information

I have a "Main Phone Number" Column and this pulls a telephone number to show in GridView. The number is only 10 digits, no formatting...(i.e. 999-999-9999)

I am trying to make GridView take the 9999999999 and make it (999) 999-9999

If I look at the DataFormatString I have tried many combinations of "{0:(###) ###-####}" with and without the quotations and also with all zeroes instead of pound signs.

Through my research it seemed that if I want to use DataFormatString I need to make my phone number in my database an int. So I deleted my table and re-created it from a varchar to an int. I get to the DataFormatString by clicking on Gridview Tasks (arrow at top right of GridView)... then "Edit columns"... then under "Selected Fields" I click the name of the column... "Main Phone Number" then on the under "CommandField properties" I scroll down to "DataFormatString".

I hope I am not being too detailed. I have really appreciated all the help.

I found this:

http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=328173

but i don't know how i would go about using it.. seeing as  how because my code was done by Visual Studio... some of it looks like this

---

UPDATE: I posted the wrong code originally, either way, based off what I stated Kelsey was able to suggest an answer for me that worked.

Below is my new code WITH the corrections that Kelly gave.

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="EmpId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
            EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." CellPadding="4" 
        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="136px" Width="299px" 
              AllowSorting="True">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpId" HeaderText="EmpId" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="EmpId" Visible="False" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" 
                    SortExpression="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" 
                    SortExpression="LastName" />
<%--                <asp:BoundField DataField="MainPhoneNumber" HeaderText="Main Phone Number" 
                    SortExpression="MainPhoneNumber" />--%>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Main Phone Number"> 
                <ItemTemplate> 
                 <asp:Literal ID="litPhone"  runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", Int64.Parse(Eval("MainPhoneNumber").ToString())) %>' /> 
                </ItemTemplate> 
                </asp:TemplateField> 

            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: @patco258 Your `GridView` code would be the most helpful here.

Comment: I updated this post with the GridView code with the correction you gave. It works.

Furthermore, before the change instead of the template field it was the boundfield that was there, just like Kelsey has in her answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you didn't post your `GridView` code I have to assume that your columns are using a `BoundField` like this or something similar:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="MainPhoneNumber" DataFormatString="{0:(###) ###-####}" />
```

Since it is a string, you can't use the `DataFormatString` property so you will need to change your `BoundField` to a `TemplateField`.  Just replace your `BoundField` with the following `TemplateField` and it should work:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="litPhone" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", Int64.Parse(Eval("MainPhoneNumber").ToString())) %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The key here is the code that evaluates the databound field and converts it to an `Int64` so that the string formatter will work.  Note that I am using an `Int64` and not just an `int` which is 32 bit because a 10 digit number will not fit.

I have tested it and it works :)

Comment: Awesome. I will check this out when I get to work. Thank you so much. I actually thought I posted all the GridView Code I needed. I guess I didn't. There was a part of the code that apparently formats the colors.. grid size.. etc.. I didn't know it would also be the key part of the field formatting.. I figured that was the code I posted that calls the information, guess I was wrong. 

I am very new to asp.net and vb.net.. as of about 1 month ago. I love it. It's like a puzzle. 

When I get it working I will make a post with the steps I took. Thank you so much for all your help.

Comment: Before I first posted I deleted my table and re-made it with the EmpID being an int in SQL Management Studio. Should I change that back to a varchar(50) or does it even matter since I will be replacing my code with what you stated? 

As I understand it, the "template" will convert the data into an Int64 and it doesn't matter if I have my data in a field as a string or an int.. but I could be wrong.

Comment: @patco258 My answer assumed your phone number field was a string as you stated above.  If it is an integer you wouldn't need to do all this extra work but since it is a string, you will require a template field like I posted to do a little extra work is happening inline in the `Text` property of the `Literal`.

Comment: I didn't mean to confuse. i acutally do have this written in my original post...


" So I deleted my table and re-created it from a varchar to an int."


In short. i deleted my table since it was a varcar datatype.. and made the datatype an int from SQL Management Studio. i hope this clears things up. I appreciate the help. Honestly, i am all new to this so even though it's an int in my SQL Management Studio table... I don't know if I am some how making it a string by accident. I have the textbox field and that value goes into the SQL database, and that value back to the Gridview.

Comment: This worked. The only thing I added was a header in the <asp:TemplateField>

Example:
> <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Main Phone Number"> 


Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Just bear in mind that if the string coming back from the database contains anything that can't be parsed by Int64.Parse, you'll get an unhandled exception. Use Int64.TryParse instead, if you want to use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

On dynamic columns - not as easy...
I went after the data-source (MS SQL) with a udf.

```
/*
    print dbo.formatPhone('1234567');
    print dbo.formatPhone('1234567890');
    print dbo.formatphone('(314)522-4949');
    print dbo.formatPhone('(314) 522-4949 x 104');
*/

create Function [udf_FormatPhone]
(
    @rawPhone as varChar(50) = null
) Returns VarChar(50) 
As
begin 
Declare @formatPhone varChar(50);
Declare @len int;

set @rawPhone = replace(@rawPhone,'(','');
set @rawPhone = replace(@rawPhone,')','');
set @rawPhone = replace(@rawPhone,'-','');
set @rawPhone = replace(@rawPhone,' ','');
set @len=len(@rawPhone)

set @formatPhone =Case
when @len < 7   then @rawPhone
when @len =7    then Substring(@RawPhone,1,3) + '-' + substring(@RawPhone,4,4)
when @len =10   then substring(@RawPhone,1,3) + '-' + substring(@RawPhone,4,3) + '-' + substring(@RawPhone,7,4)
when @len > 10  then substring(@rawPhone,1,3) + '-' + substring(@rawPhone,4,3) + '-' + substring(@RawPhone,7,4) + ' ' + substring(@rawPhone,11,50)
else    @RawPhone
end

return(@formatPhone);
end
```

and the result of "3015551212x234"

[image: Correctly formatted]

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to modify the SELECT statement to cast to a number (that can hold enough digits) as long as you are sure it does not contain anything characters that are not numbers. In SQL Server this is done via the built in CAST or CONVERT functions:

```
SELECT CAST(Phone as BIGINT) as Phone
```

Then a boundfield with DataFormatString will work as expected:

```
DataFormatString="{0:(###) ###-####}"
```

I generally avoid template fields because then I cannot set

```
EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True"
```

on a gridview. I also like the leaner code from the boundfield.