# Input string was not in a correct format for Phone number

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written below lines of codes in grid view

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="Phone1">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="lblPhone" runat="server">
   <%# Eval("Phone1") != DBNull.Value ? String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}",Convert.ToInt64(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Phone1"))) : Eval("Phone1") %>
  </asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

When I run this in the browser, it throws an error message

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: it means your Phone1 value is not valid for conversion to Int64. Can you post the actual value?

Comment: Is `Phone1` column set to `varchar` in table?

Comment: Yes it is set nvarchar in the table

Comment: This format is not getting applied to phone numbers. Please help

Comment: You can move code in OnDataBound event to debug. You have to check Phone1 column values

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427739/format-telephone-number-in-gridview